# Encoding from Uncompressed IEEE floating-point audio to AAC using Media Foundation

Tags: c++, audio, ms-media-foundation

I've been trying to use Media Foundation to encode Uncompressed IEEE floating-point audio(**MFAudioFormat_Float**) to AAC(**MFAudioFormat_AAC)** but as it seems the AAC Encoder can only take Uncompressed PCM audio(**MFAudioFormat_PCM**) as input - [AAC Encoder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd742785(v=vs.85).aspx).

When I use MFTEnum or MFTEnumEx functions:

```
hr = MFTEnum(
    MFT_CATEGORY_AUDIO_ENCODER,
    NULL,                                 // Reserved
    &tininfo /* MFAudioFormat_Float */,   // Input type to match.
    &toutinfo /* MFAudioFormat_AAC */,    // Output type to match.
    NULL,                                 // Attributes to match. (None.)
    &pCLSIDs,                             // Receives a pointer to an array of CLSIDs.
    &count                                // Receives the size of the array.
    );
```

It doesn't find any available codecs(`count == 0`).

So is it at all possible to use Media Foundation to do this? Can I find some other codec and install it and use? Or maybe there is some other way to do it and I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: Apparently you need to get `MFAudioFormat_PCM` first.

Comment: @RomanR. You mean first encoding **MFAudioFormat_Float** to **MFAudioFormat_PCM** and then encoding it to **MFAudioFormat_AAC**? I thought about that but there didn't seem to be  a codec for that either. At least when I tried the same `MFTEnum` function with `tininfo` given **MFAudioFormat_PCM** and `toutinfo` given **MFAudioFormat_PCM** it didn't find any codecs. Also I'm not sure if that would give an optimal performance.

Comment: I am under impression that conversion from IEEE to 16-bit PCM exists. It is either [Audio Resampler DSP](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff819070) or wrapped ACM codec. Picking up those through `MFTEnum` is a question of registration/enumeration. The optimal performance considerations are premature because you need to get it working all together in first place.

Answer (score 0):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/medfound/aac-encoder

### Input Types

```
MF_MT_SUBTYPE                   Subtype.            Must be MFAudioFormat_PCM.
MF_MT_AUDIO_BITS_PER_SAMPLE     Bits per sample.    Must be 16.
MF_MT_AUDIO_SAMPLES_PER_SECOND  Samples per second. The following values are supported: 44100 (44.1 KHz) 48000 (48 KHz)
```

Comment: also to convert Float to 16 bit PCM just multiply you floats [-1,1] by `32767` and then cast to `int16_t`